How can create an armature or rigging with mocap data in Blender 4.0?
In Blender 4.0, after importing a mocap file, the object file (which includes the mocap marker points), pose, and animation are combined into a single hierarchy. I would like to know how to bake the animation into each individual object so that I can apply it to an armature.
